# The search fails With AJAX call

Tags: javascript, datatables

The data search works fine for normal table data. When Iam filling the table body with Ajax call the search is not working.

I am using AJAX call to fill the table body. My table search works well If there is some Dummy Data without Ajax call. After the Ajax call the search is not working...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="myTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody id="userdetails1">

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.0/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/admin-dashboard.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
    $('#myTable input').on('keyup', function() {
        table.search(this.value).draw();
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Re-initialize by:-  $('#myTable').DataTable();
Your Table in your ajax success or .then(data=>{}) After filling the body using ajax

Comment: Where is `table` variable coming from? I mean where is the declaration and initialization of `table` variable?

Comment: @Rishabh , It is not working. Though I did it by your way.

Comment: https://codepen.io/jithendraathipatla/pen/JQMxvg?editors=1111 

CodePen link by yhe way If you wish to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The issue is not with your ajax calls 
rather it's with your data-table initializing
```

with reference to your codepen link:
https://codepen.io/jithendraathipatla/pen/JQMxvg?editors=1111

do this: in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
 function filterGlobal () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable().search(
        $('#global_filter').val(),

    ).draw();
}

function filterColumn ( i ) {
    $('#myTable').DataTable().column( i ).search(
        $('#col'+i+'_filter').val(),

    ).draw();
}

    $('input.global_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
        filterGlobal();
    } );

    $('input.column_filter').on( 'keyup click', function () {
        filterColumn( $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-column') );
    } );
} );
```

and in your js file replace your code with:

```
var waitlistTable=[];
waitlistdatashow();
function waitlistdatashow(){
    console.log("hi");
    var data = {"hosted_event_id": "testkonfhub-php-ban963c6ec2",
    "user_id" : "1548232247"
     };
// document.getElementById("userdetails").innerHTML = "<i class=\"fa fa-refresh fa-spin\" style=\"font-size:48px\"></i> ";
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://mr6akjmp7f.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/default/konfhub_event_display_wailist_details",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    async:false,
    success: function (data) {

        console.log(data);

        waitlistTable=data.participant_details;
        console.log(waitlistTable);
        //document.getElementById("event_name1").innerHTML = waitlistTable.event_name;
        for(var i=0; i < waitlistTable.length; i++){
            $("#userdetails1").append(
               //"<th>Date & Time of Purchase</th>" +
                "<tr>"+
                "<td style='cursor: default'>" + waitlistTable[i].name + "</td>" +
                "<td style='cursor: default'>" +
                "    <span class=\"block-email\" >" + waitlistTable[i].email_id.slice(0, 25) + "</span>" +
                "</td>" +
                "<td class=\"desc\">" + waitlistTable[i].phone_number + "</td>" +
                "<td class=\"desc\">" + waitlistTable[i].organisation + "</td>" +
                 "<td class=\"desc\"  id=\"waitlisttext\" style=\"color:orange\">" + waitlistTable[i].ticket_status + "</td>" +
                // "<td><textarea  id=" + "lead_text".concat(no_of_participant) + " rows=\"1\" cols=\"50\" type=\"text\" style=\"width:100%;border: 1px solid lightslategrey;padding: 4px;border-radius: 4px;\" placeholder=\"write comments here..\">" + returnLeadText(king[no_of_participant].misc) + "</textarea></td>" +
               // "<td><span id=" + "approve".concat(no_of_participant) + " class='fas fa-check-circle click-check' onclick=\"approveWaitlist(" + no_of_participant + ")\" style=\"cursor:pointer;font-size: 25px;color:green\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Approve\">&nbsp&nbsp</span>"+
                //"<div id=" + "delete-waitlist".concat(no_of_participant) + " class='far fa-times-circle click-check1' onclick=\"deleteWaitlistRecord(" + no_of_participant + ")\" style=\"cursor:pointer; font-size: 25px;color:red\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Reject\"></div></td>" +
                "<\tr>"+
                "<hr>"


            );
            // if(waitlistTable[i].status=="ACTIVE"){
            //     document.getElementById("refundbtn".concat(i)).style.display = "block";
            //     document.getElementById("cancelbtn".concat(i)).style.display = "block";
    }
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
}
    });
}
```